# How to get verification code image from Webbrowser control? Be an Image object

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

It's verification code image.
So please don't answered download by url.

As some bug, "copy commmand" sometimes just copy url, not image.
So please don't answered using IHTMLControlRange.execCommand methed.

Some website is not HTML5 page.
So please don't answered get it by canvas tag.

....
Any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... I'm try to download... and it works!

Just faking the request with the same parameters as page in the browser control.

```
var hRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp("/*Rand Code Url*/?rnd=" + new Random().NextDouble());
hRequest.Accept = "image/png, image/svg+xml, image/jxr, image/*; q=0.8, */*; q=0.5";
hRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate");
hRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, /*Page AcceptLanguage*/);
hRequest.KeepAlive = true;
string cookie = "";
webBrowser.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { cookie = webBrowser.Document.Cookie; });
hRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookie);
hRequest.Headers.Add("DNT", "1");
hRequest.Host = /*page window.location.host*/;
hRequest.Referer = /*page.referer*/;
hRequest.UserAgent = /*page navigator.userAgent*/;
hRequest.Method = "GET";
var hResponse = hRequest.GetResponse();
var response = hResponse.GetResponseStream();
List<byte> data = new List<byte>();
//read stream
while (true)
{
    int i = response.ReadByte();
    if (i >= 0)
        data.Add((byte)i);
    else
        break;
}
if (data.Count == 0) return "";//if not succes, return empty string
//convert to Base64 string
string RandBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(data.ToArray());
hResponse.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are using Winforms you can use graphics object to take a screenshot of everything being rendered in the WebBroser control.

Here is how you could do this:

```
   private void CaptureImage()
    {


        int width, height;
        width = webBrowser1.ClientRectangle.Width;
        height = webBrowser1.ClientRectangle.Height;
        using (Bitmap image = new Bitmap(width, height))
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
            {
                Point p, upperLeftSource, upperLeftDestination;
                p = new Point(0, 0);
                upperLeftSource = webBrowser1.PointToScreen(p);
                upperLeftDestination = new Point(0, 0);
                Size blockRegionSize = webBrowser1.ClientRectangle.Size;
                graphics.CopyFromScreen(upperLeftSource, upperLeftDestination, blockRegionSize);
            }
            //saveout the image
            var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, "image.png");
            image.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

        }
    }
```

Just so we are clear, a [Bitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) is a specific implementation of System.Drawing.Image.